# Fetch specific parts of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-5

Given the (relatively long) string:

`string` = `"Checks for load balancers with listeners that do not use recommended security configurations for encrypted communication. AWS recommends using a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL), up-to-date security policies, and ciphers and protocols that are secure.<br/>\nWhen you use a secure protocol for a front-end connection (client to load balancer), the requests are encrypted between your clients and the load balancer, which is more secure.<br/>\nElastic Load Balancing provides predefined security policies  with ciphers and protocols that adhere to AWS security best practices. New versions of predefined policies are released as new configurations become available. <br/><br/>\n<b>Alert Criteria</b><br/>\nYellow: A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL). <br/>\nYellow: A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy. <br/>\nYellow: A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended. <br/>\nRed: A load balancer listener uses an insecure cipher or protocol.<br/><br/>\n<b>Recommended Action</b>\n<ul><li>If the traffic to your load balancer must be secure, use either the HTTPS or the SSL protocol for the front-end connection.</li>\n<li>Upgrade your load balancer to the latest version of the predefined SSL security policy.</li> \n<li>Use only the recommended ciphers and protocols.</li> </ul>\nFor more information, see <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html\">Listener Configurations for Elastic Load Balancing</a>.<br/><br/>\n<b>Additional Resources</b><br/>\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-elb-listenerconfig-quickref.html\">Listener Configurations Quick Reference</a><br/>\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-config-update.html\">Update SSL Negotiation Configuration of Your Load Balancer</a><br/>\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-ssl-security-policy.html\">SSL Negotiation Configurations for Elastic Load Balancing</a><br/>\n<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-policy-table.html\">SSL Security Policy Table</a><br/>\n"`

I would like to have a method, where I pass one of the statuses as an argument:

- `'Green'`
- `'Yellow'`
- `'Red'`

which would return me an array of full sencentes, that follow this string (no matter, how many occurences of the string there is).

```
def status_description(string, status)
  # manipulate string and return status description(s)
end
```

With the above string, I would expect

```
status_description(string, 'Yellow')
```

to return

```
[
  'A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL).',
  'A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy.',
  'A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended.'
]
```

And

```
status_description(string, 'Red')
```

to return

```
['A load balancer listener uses an insecure cipher or protocol.']
```

The string will always have the same structure, meaning, that status descriptions always follow this part:

```
\n<b>Alert Criteria</b><br/>
```

If you can make the method return a hash containing all the statuses (it is usually some or all of three aforementioned) with its' descriptions would be just perfect! Something like:

```
{
  'Green' => ['some green desc']
  'Yellow' => ['some yellow desc', 'another yellow desc'],
  'Red' => ['some red desc']
}
```

---

I will also need to get the array of `'Recommended Action'`:

```
[
  'If the traffic to your load balancer must be secure, use either the HTTPS or the SSL protocol for the front-end connection.',
  'Upgrade your load balancer to the latest version of the predefined SSL security policy.',
  'Use only the recommended ciphers and protocols.'
]
```

---

I have little to zero experience with regex, which in this case might be not so trivial.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Too much scrolling to read the actual string. Undo it after some time if you will.

Comment: @MYGz it is meant to be just copied :) But your edit (even though it looks ugly now) makes it more "readable"

Comment: I think you should run this through a HTML parser and extract the semantic text, otherwise the periods in links' urls make it hard to define a sentence.

Comment: don't see a green in there. You can try this for red and yellow: `Yellow:\s*.*?\.` and `Red:\s*.*?\.` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IxoPB0/2

Comment: @MYGz yea, as I said there could 1, 2 or 3 statuses. I'll try, thx!

Comment: @MYGz it works very nicely. Could you please, also, hint me to the `Recommended Action` regex solution? Thx in advance!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko `Recommended Action` would require a bit long regex. Check my solution with BeautifulSoup. You can implement something similar in ruby. BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser. When you call `.text` on that object, all HTML tags disappear, and then you can simply use regex to get what you want.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Check the regex for `Recommended Action` in answers. See if it works for you. The desired text is captured in groups. Just extract the text from groups and store it in array.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Nothing you couldn't have done yourself with some experimentation! You don't need regex at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
def status_description(str, color)
  str.scan(/(?<=#{color}:\s).*?[.!?]/i)
end

status_description(string, "yellow")
  #=> ["A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL).",
  #    "A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy.",
  #    "A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended."]

status_description(string, "green")
  #=> [] 

status_description(string, "red")
  #=> ["A load balancer listener uses an insecure cipher or protocol."]
```

For

```
color = "yellow"
```

the regex is

```
r = /
    (?<=       # begin a positive lookbehind
      #{color} # match the value of the variable `color`
      :\s      # match a colon followed by whitespace
    )          # close positive lookbehind
    .*?        # match any number of any characters, lazily
    [.!?]      # match a character that terminates a sentence
    /ix        # case-indifference and free-spacing regex definition modes
  #=> /
  #=> (?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
  #     yellow # match the value of the variable `color`
  #     :\s    # match a colon followed by whitespace
  #   )        # close positive lookbehind
  #   .*?      # match any number of any characters, lazily
  #   [.!?]    # match a character that terminates a sentence
  #   /ix
```

Alternatively, as requested,

```
["green", "yellow", "red"].each_with_object({}) { |c,h|
  h[c] = status_description(string, c) }
  #=> {"green" =>[],
  #    "yellow"=>[
  #      "A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL).",
  #      "A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy.",
  #      "A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended."
  #    ],
  #    "red"=>["A load balancer listener uses an insecure cipher or protocol."]
  #   }
```

You can do the following to pull out the sentences that comprise "recommended action".<sup>1</sup>

```
r0 = /
     \n<b>Recommended\sAction<\/b>\n<ul><li> # match string
     \K                   # discard everything matched so far
     .+?                  # match any number of any character, lazily (?)
     (?=<\/li>\s<\/ul>)   # match string
     /mx                  # multiline and free-spacing regex definition modes

r1 = /<\/li>\s*\n\s*<li>/ # match string
```

```
string[r0].split(r1)
  #=> ["If the traffic to your load balancer must be secure, use either the \  
  #     HTTPS or the SSL protocol for the front-end connection.",
  #    "Upgrade your load balancer to the latest version of the predefined \
  #     SSL security policy.",
  #    "Use only the recommended ciphers and protocols."]
```

Note that

```
string[r0]
  #=> "If the traffic to your load balancer must be secure, use either \
  #    the HTTPS or the SSL protocol for the front-end connection.\
  #    </li>\n<li>Upgrade your load balancer to the latest version of the \
  #    predefined SSL security policy.</li> \n<li>Use only the recommended \
  #    ciphers and protocols."
```

<sup>1. In constructing `r0` I replaced the single space in `"Recommended Action"` and `"(?=<\/li> <\/ul>)"` with `\s`. That is only needed when the regex is defined in free-spacing mode (`/x`), which disregards spaces. Also, `\n<b>Recommended\sAction<\/b>\n<ul><li>\K` can be replaced with a positive lookbehind: `(?<=\n<b>Recommended\sAction<\/b>\n<ul><li>)`. Lastly, I formated the return strings so they could be read without scrolling horizontally</sup>.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cary! Perfect explanation! Can I also ask you about `'Recommended Action'`?

Comment: @Michael, I don't understand the reason for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I was a in a rush and didn't realize that this is the return value as shown in IRB, but instead thought you had mistakenly commented out the closing of the regular expression and the modifiers (`# /ix`). All good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
[^.]*Yellow:([^.]*).
```

Change the Yellow with a variable in the method.
Group 1 will return the description you desired.

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1UQl9g/8)

Sample Ruby Code:

```
re = /[^.]*Yellow:([^.]*)./m

str = 'your large string goes here ................'
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

[Run it here](https://repl.it/FHFR/0)

Output:

```
[" A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL)"]
[" A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy"]
[" A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It returns an array of arrays, whereas I need an array of strings (I could use `flatten`, but would be better to correctly grep the string). Also, How about `Recommended Action`?

Answer (score 1):

Try these

Regex for Colors:

```
Yellow:\s*.*?\.
Red:\s*.*?\.
Green:\s*.*?\.
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IxoPB0/2

Regex for Recommended Actions in given string.

```
(?<=Recommended Action)<.*?li>(.*?)<\/li>.*?li>(.*?)<\/li>.*?li>(.*?)<\/li>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IxoPB0/3

Comment: A Ruby response is desired. If you can't give one that's okay, there's two other good answers here. Adding Python just confuses things.

Comment: @tadman I understand. The other answers here don't solve the problem he is stuck at. This is just to show the logic/steps to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Since this text is actually HTML, a parser (e.g. [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)) is a better idea than Regex. The only problem is that this HTML structure isn't a tree, so it makes it a bit harder to parse.

`String#split` goes a long way with this example, without needing any Regex at all.

The code first splits the huge strings into multiple text blocks ("Alert Criteria", "Recommended Action", ...).

For "Alert Criteria" block, it splits each line around `:` to get the color and text, and creates a Hash of arrays.

For "Recommended Action", it just looks for text between `<li>` and `</li>`.

```
blocks = string.split("<br/><br/>\n").map do |block|
  block.split('<br/>').map(&:strip)
end

### Analyzing criterias
criterias_block = blocks.find { |block| block.first.include?('Alert Criteria') }

criterias_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

if criterias_block
  header, *criterias = criterias_block
  criterias.each_with_object(criterias_hash) do |line, hash|
    color, criteria = line.split(': ')
    hash[color] << criteria
  end
end

pp criterias_hash
# {"Yellow"=>
#   ["A load balancer has no listener that uses a secure protocol (HTTPS or SSL).",
#    "A load balancer listener uses an outdated predefined SSL security policy.",
#    "A load balancer listener uses a cipher or protocol that is not recommended."],
#  "Red"=>["A load balancer listener uses an insecure cipher or protocol."]}

### Recommend actions
actions_block = blocks.find { |block| block.first.include?('Recommended Action') }

if actions_block
  require 'nokogiri'
  actions_html = Nokogiri::HTML(actions_block.first)
  pp actions_html.css('li').map(&:text)
end

# ["If the traffic to your load balancer must be secure, use either the HTTPS or the SSL protocol for the front-end connection.",
#  "Upgrade your load balancer to the latest version of the predefined SSL security policy.",
#  "Use only the recommended ciphers and protocols."]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! With the given example both work great, but I realized (and was *very* unpleasantly surprised) that Amazon formatted these descriptions differently, so I decided to create a manual hash of `Recommended Action`s (I only have 15 of these descriptions) P.S. Shame on me - I never had a chance to use Nokogiri - thanks a lot for bringing it up, indeed with a rich HTML markup using it makes total sense.

Comment: What do the others strings look like?

Comment: [here they are](https://gist.github.com/andreydeineko/864cf03223bf259ad7c4a955d5f0a3fc). I really don't think it's worth writing a method for it since there are only 15 of them as of now.